# inconsistent font-family selection on Chrome mobile

Tags: font-family

My pretty simple web page has an internal stylesheet that contains:

```
BODY { font-family:Segoe UI; }
```

This works in Chrome and IE, on both desktop and mobile. Only for IOS/Safari, this doesn't work, I need an alternative font there (don't I?).

The issue: when I add any alternative font-family, Chrome on mobile no longer uses Segoe UI. E.g. when I change the style above to:

```
BODY { font-family:Segoe UI, Open Sans, sans-serif; }
```

then Chrome on mobile (tested under Oreo 8.1 with latest version Chrome) no longer uses Segoe UI. Using single or double quotes doesn't make a difference.

Any ideas about cause and/or solutions?

Answer (score 0):

After looking better: on mobile, Chrome can't display 'Segoe UI'. When no alternative is mentioned in the stylesheet, Chrome chooses Roboto.